# Updating existing application in App Store with new InApp Purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have a problem regarding updating previous application in appstore.

The app which is present over there in appstore had used Bundle Identifier portion of an App ID is substituted with a wild-card.

Now I want to update my new application (which contains In App purchase) over it.

Does apple allows me to do so as previous application has wild character in App ID?

If not then why the application in appstore shows the option of "Manage Your InApp Purchase" into it.

Any solution will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a tech note on this but the only reference I can find on what you need to do is at the bottom of the [iOS Team Administration Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs.html) under `Updating Your App to Include APNS, iCloud, In-App Purchase, or Game Center Requires an Explicit App ID`